Empty records in Drupal CMS after bulk insert
I recently migrated data from development project into staging server and I resolved the conflicts and the data is present in DB but in CMS it is showing empty records. (check pic)

I cleared the cache but still not showing and in the site UI nothing is showing.

did your data got migrated properly, can you view / edit the content via urls like node/{nid} or node/{nid}/edit

I tried but I could not edit or view the content. does this mean the migration was not proper?

the migrations was not proper and after many tries all tables were migrated correctly.
